# Why is my VS Code installation of the Dracula Official theme seemingly not appearing the same as a reference screenshot?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to use [Dracula Official](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dracula-theme.theme-dracula) theme in my VSCode. But I am not getting my text like the official image below.

I am not getting the exact font and italic text.

My texts are like below.

[image]

How can I make my text like official image ?

[image]

Comment: type the exact same code in the exact same programming language (javascript) as the screenshot you're trying to get your to look like. Then take a screenshot and show that. And you _still_ haven't edited your title.

Comment: I highly suspect this is just a case of different languages having different colour mappings within the same colour theme for different syntactic / semantic tokens. Either that, or my next guess is the screenshot from the extension docs is out of date.

Comment: Have you asked in the Dracula github support page?